# Speed up Slow Mongo / Mongoose Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a the following model and indexes:

```
    var mySchema = new Schema({
    page: String,
    date: Date,
    data: Object,
    _page: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Page'
    },
});

mySchema.index({_page: 1, date: 1 }, {unique: true});
```

And this query:

```
mySchema.find({
    _page: page._id,
    date: {
       $gte: date1,
       $lt: date2
    }
})
.sort({
   date: 1
})
.exec((err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

And it logs out like this:

```
myschema.find({ date: { '$gte': new Date("Thu, 16 Nov 2017 23:00:00 GMT"), '$lt': new Date("Thu, 14 Dec 2017 23:00:00 GMT") }, _page: ObjectId("5a57b30bf54be100c315f2f5") }, { sort: { date: 1 }, fields: {} })
```

And it takes about 1 second to return ~30 results from a table with about 4000 documents and ~60mb.

DB is a replica cluster on mlab, query speed is pretty similar weather I connect from localhost or my server (db and server in w-europe)

Is there any way to speed this up? Am I indexing or querying wrong?

Comment: It's not clear if your database server is running on network or locally. There are many factors leading to slowness. memory, disk, network latency etc.

Comment: @Saleem updated the question. hope this helps...

Comment: Can you post output of running an `explain()` command?

Comment: @Seb, please include output from `explain` as suggested by @Zlatko

Answer (score 2):

Using lean() method can improve the performance of find query in mongoose. The reason for it is that using this function returns plain Javascript objects instead of extra Mongoose methods like save function, getters and setters. If you want to check the performance difference of a plain Javascript object and Mongoose Object, you can visit [this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

However, you can take advantage of it for only read operations. So, if its just find operation, you can use lean().

```
mySchema.find(...).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This made a significant difference. Thank you for your answer!